# Map multiple columns from pandas dataframe to a dictionary and conditionally return a value to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns and a dictionary with keys that correspond to the column names. I want to check the column values with respect to the dictionary values and return either a 'yes' or 'no' based on whether the column value meets a "greater than or equal to" condition.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
dfdict = {'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4], 'col3': [3.2, 4.2, 7.7]}
checkdict = {'col1': 2, 'col2': 3, 'col3': 1.5}
df = pd.DataFrame(dfdict)
```

For each column, for each row, check whether the row value is greater than or equal to than the value in the dictionary. For that row, if any of the columns meet the condition, return a "yes" to a newly created column, else return a "no".

What I've tried:

```
def checkcond(element):
    if not math.isnan(element):
        x = checkdict[element]
        return 1 if element >= x else 0
    else:
        pass

df['test'] = df.applymap(checkcond)
```

but of course this doesn't work because the row value is supplied to the checkcond function rather than the column name and row.

I also tried:

```
df['test'] = pd.np.where(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].ge(0).any(1, skipna=True), 'Y', 'N')
```

But that will only take one value for the "ge" condition, whereas I want to check the row value with respect to the dictionary value for each of the columns.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You have "greater than or equal to" in one spot and "greater than" in another, so I guess it is the first one ;)

Comment: Good catch, edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your dictionary to Series and perform a simple comparison:

```
df.ge(pd.Series(checkdict)).replace({True: 'yes', False: 'no'})
```

output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0   no   no  yes
1   no   no  yes
2  yes  yes  yes
```

To get aggregation per row:

```
df['any'] = df.ge(pd.Series(checkdict)).any(1).map({True: 'yes', False: 'no'})
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  any
0     1     2   3.2  yes
1     2     3   4.2  yes
2     3     4   7.7  yes
```

Comment: Sorry @Scott ;)

Comment: That is a super elegant solution, although the question was technically greater than, so df['any'] = df.gt(pd.Series(checkdict)).any(1).map({True: 'yes', False: 'no'}) is correct. Ignore that, the question is greater than or equal, the description of logic is greater than, so your solution is perfect. Just to note you can use gt as an alternative!

Comment: @IainD this was my comment to OP, there is ambiguity on the gt/ge, anyway this is minor ;)